# Cannot read property '0' of undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am getting TypeError  Cannot read property '0' of undefined . Below is the code. fsIncomeStatementTable is 
fsIncomeStatementTable is an array of arrays .I have noticed that has one row of undefined. How do i check
for that row ?

I am getting error if i try my solution saying cannot bind ngif

Code

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let row of fsIncomeStatementTable | slice:1" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[0] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[1] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[2] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[3]}">
      <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1">{{cell | shortNumberDivideByThousand: 0 | number:'.0-0'}}</td>
   </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Solution

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of fsIncomeStatementTable | slice:1" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[0] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[1] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[2] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[3]}">
     <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
     <td *ngif="row !== undefined"> </td>
     <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1">{{cell | shortNumberDivideByThousand: 0 | number:'.0-0'}}</td>
   </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: The *row* itself is always defined since you do not add an "undefined" to a collection. The directives you are using looks like operating on a child property of the "row" and the child property is getting null. You need to check what property is being used and then handle it within the directive

Answer (score 0):

Move the `*ngFor` up into an `ng-container` and then put an `*ngIf` on the `tr`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let row of fsIncomeStatementTable | slice:1">
  <tr *ngIf="row" [ngClass]="{'net-cost': row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[0] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[1] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[2] || row[0] === incomeStatementStyles[3]}">
    <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
    <td *ngif="row !== undefined"> </td>
    <td *ngFor="let cell of row | slice:1">{{cell | shortNumberDivideByThousand: 0 | number:'.0-0'}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue):

> The Angular  is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Comment: getting error Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. (">
                                    <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                                    <td [ERROR ->]*ngif="row !== undefined"> </td>

Comment: Make sure the `i` is capitalized. e.g. `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to access your row here

```
 <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
```

even if it is undefined.

your code should rater look like this:

```
 <td *ngif="row !== undefined">{{row[0]}}</td>
 <td *ngif="row === undefined"> </td>
```

Comment: getting error Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. ("> <td>{{row[0]}}</td> <td [ERROR ->]*ngif="row !== undefined"> </td> –

Comment: import angular FormsModule.

Comment: I have added the import to its component but getting the same error

Comment: you need to import it in your app.module